# How to set canvas url for app on Facebook

Tags: facebook-apps

on the app setting-Basic page, "Select how your app integrates with Facebook", I choose "App on Facebook", but Canvas URL is hidden if I disable Unity Integration. While If I enable Unity Integration, I have to enter the Unity Binary URL, I have no idea what it is. Looks like the doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/ is outdated because there is nothing about "Ubity Integration" option on the snapshot. Anybody help me out, please

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a new Facebook bug. It used to work a few days ago.

Edit: It was fixed today by Facebook.

Comment: Unless you can show it's a bug, this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Turns out it is a bug. Facebook has fixed it.

Comment: it only asks for secure URL (https) so can't we use fb login on http ?